# How does postgres calculate multi column hashes?

Tags: postgresql

In PG I have a table which is using `partition by hash (*text*, *bigint*)` looking at a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64647956/what-hashing-algorithm-function-is-used-by-postgres-for-partition-by-hash) the functions used for hashing can be seen however I'm unsure which function is used to build combined hashes?

Is it treating the partition keys as a record and using `hash_record`?

Ultimately I want to know this to rebuild the hashing function in Java to optimise reads and writes to specific partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [hash_combine64](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/hashfn_8h.html#a0dbcc68d1e810b0b545c2b654ebad7ec) is used for calculating the ultimate hash value. According to the comments in the code it's based on the boost's [hash_combine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985960/c-why-is-boosthash-combine-the-best-way-to-combine-hash-values) approach. Also, you can find the whole partition calculation algorithm in [compute_partition_hash_value](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/partbounds_8c.html#a9ee72046310f11382fa771211f71e6df) function.

Comment: is there a reason I cant see the combine function when I run `\df hash_combine64` (using PG 14.5)

Comment: No idea why it's not propagated there. Historical reasons?